# Send test payload does not work on Mautic - WebHook

Tags: mautic

I'm trying to receive a request from mautic (webhook), but even the example in node/express from git from mautic doesn't work.

Does anyone know the structure that the hook should have?

my example node/express server from mautic is this
http://45.191.91.7:3000/webhook

using postman works, however using send test payload does not work